# Android GridView Items and overlaying Relative Layouts

Tags: android, gridview, android-relativelayout

I have a dynamically created GridView using a custom adapter. On clicking the GridView item, I have to display a bubble under it. I am using RelativeLayout for this, but everytime the bubble is getting displayed on the top left corner.

This my custom adapter

```
public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private GridItem[] items;

public GridAdapter(Context c) {

    mContext = c;
    items = GridItem.values();
    //inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

public int getCount() {

    return items.length;
}

public GridItem getItem(int position) {

    return items[position];
}

public long getItemId(int position) {

    return items[position].getResourceId();
}

public static class ViewHolder {

    public ImageView image;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(GridView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                GridView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        //imageView.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
    imageView.setBackgroundResource(items[position].getResourceId());
    if (position == 3) {
        ImageView helpBubble = new ImageView(mContext);

    }
    //imageView.setTag(items[position]);
    return imageView;
}
```

}

Here's the code to set the bubble

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                GridItem item = GridItem.values()[position];
                if (position != 6) {

                    Toast.makeText(HelpModeActivity.this, "Clicked on : " + item.getResourceId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();

                    LayoutInflater inflate = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    RelativeLayout helpBubble = (RelativeLayout) inflate.inflate(R.layout.bubble, null);

                    TextView helpText = (TextView) helpBubble.findViewById(R.id.bubble_text);
                    helpText.setText("Lorem Epsum Dolor Emit ab asdfj asdflqwe fsadf wqrwqer asdfasdf wfsad asdfasdf rqwerqwrw");

                    Button moreButton = (Button) helpBubble.findViewById(R.id.bubble_button);
                    moreButton.setText("More Info");

                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, item.getResourceId());

                    gridRL.addView(helpBubble, lp);
}
```

Where am I going wrong???

Comment: lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT) add this and try again...